# referencing a list item when calling a vector from a data frame in R

Tags: r

pretend I have a data frame with 4 columns, and a list that contains 3 of those column names

```
#create data with 4 columns, a-d
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(1,2,3)
c<-c(1,2,3)
d<-c(0.3,0.4,0.2)
data<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
#create a list that doesnt include d
list<-c('a','b','c')
```

I want to run a loop where I calculate values based on the sums of those columns, one at a time, and then store this information as a table that gives me the id of each column that was worked with, and the calculated value.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
#make output vectors for a loop
output.id<-c() 
output.metric<-c()
#run loop
for(i in 1:length(list)){
    #name of which id in the list you are working on
    id<-list[i]
    #compute something based on the data contained within a vector of the data frame, referencing where you are in the list
    metric<- sum(data$list[i]*data$d)/sum(data$list[i])
    #save the name of which id you were working on and the computed value for each element i
    output.id<-c(output.id,id)
    output.metric<-(output.metric,metric)
}
```

the problem is with the calculation of the metric. I want to call a column of the data based on which list item 'i' I am working on. so, when i=A, i want

```
metric<- sum(data$list[i]*data$d)/sum(data$list[i])
```

to be interpreted as

```
metric<- sum(data$a*data$d)/sum(data$a)
```

where 'list[i]' is replaced with 'a'

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code didn't work is that `data$list[i]` should be replaced with `data[[list[i]]]`. However, this whole code could be rewritten in two lines, which will make it both shorter and more efficient. I've changed your variable names so you're not overwriting the `list` and `data` functions:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, c=1:3, d=c(0.3,0.4,0.2))
lst <- c("a", "b", "c")
output.id <- lst
output.metric <- sapply(lst, function(x) sum(dat[,x]*dat$d)/sum(dat[,x]))
output.metric
#         a         b         c 
# 0.2833333 0.2833333 0.2833333
```

Another approach would be:

```
colSums(dat[,lst]*dat$d) / colSums(dat[,lst])
#         a         b         c 
# 0.2833333 0.2833333 0.2833333
```

Comment: If you're changing `list`, `data` is also a base R function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your indexing operation. You use the `$` operator, where in this case you should use `[]`. In general, you wouldnt have to use a for loop to achieve this, because many operations in R can be vectorized. But to show you how you could do it with a for loop:

```
output.id<- numeric(length(list))        #if you have to populate a vector in a for loop, it is good practice to initialize it with the correct or expected length
output.metric<-numeric(length(list))

for(i in 1:length(list)){

  id<-list[i]

  #note the difference in the following line where i use [] instead of $ and id instead of list[i]

  metric<- sum(data[,id]*data$d)/sum(data[,id])

  output.id[i] <-  id              
  output.metric[i] <- metric
}

#this will create a data.frame with results
output <- data.frame(id = output.id, metric = output.metric)
```

I suggest you read an R tutorial/introduction to learn more about subsetting etc.